# Excel function to present total event occurrences based on month and year of event

Tags: excel

In my excel file, we are tracking items in for repairs with their corresponding dates of arrival.  The dates start in A3 and continue to A23.  I need a function to output how many items arrived each month based on their date of arrival in C45 (July), D45 (August), ect.  Is this  even possible?

There are no values corresponding to these dates.  That is why my previous attempts at using the LOOKUP function have failed.  Thanks.

```
Arrival Date
7/10/2012
9/10/2012
9/18/2012
9/18/2012
9/19/2012


Total Failures      July '12    August '12  September '12   
Historical         1                0                4
```

Comment: Are you looking for a true VBA function, or a formula that will count?

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Put `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$3:$A$23)= 7))` in C45

Put `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$3:$A$23)= 8))` in D45

courtesy: www.chandoo.org